# Which Schengen visa to I require, tourist or business?

Tags: visas, schengen

I am 18 yrs old. I am going to Portugal to attend Web Summit. I don’t have a job, I am studying. Which visa do I require? business or tourist?

Comment: I thought Schengen visa is for both business and tourism..

Comment: @HeidelBerGensis Yes but their are types of schengen visa.

Comment: @mega6382: The only type of Schengen visa that's relevant for you is the ordinary type C short-stay visa.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The purpose of your visit fits tourism (this is the what you should tick on the application form).

You will need to supply:

1. Proof of funds
2. Invitation letter from the conference.
3. Airline reservation
4. Hotel reservation (in your name) for the period of your stay.

In addition to the normal requirements (photo + application form + insurance + passport).

Your passport should be valid for 6 months *after* you intend to return.

You are a high risk applicant - therefore you should demonstrate significant ties to your home country before applying.

There is only one short stay temporary visa (the "Schengen visa"). The difference is the documentation you need to provide for the application which depends on the purpose of your trip - but the visa you get (for short trips) is the same.